# A question on the manifold $ \{n\otimes n-m\otimes m:n,m\in S^2,(n,m)=0\} $.

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Consider a manifold $ N $ defined as follows
$$
N=\{n\otimes n-m\otimes m:n,m\in S^2,\,\,(n,m)=0\}\subset M^{3\times 3},
$$
where $ S^2 $ denotes the two dimensional sphere, $ (\cdot,\cdot) $ represents the inner product of the space $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ and $ M^{3\times 3} $ denotes the set of $ 3\times 3 $ matrices. For a cloase curve $ \alpha:S^1\to N $, we can consider the homotopy class of it. Define maps
$$
\pi_1:N\to\mathbb{R}P^2,\,\,\pi_2:N\to\mathbb{R}P^2
$$
as follows. For any $ A\in N $, we can represent $ A=n\otimes n-m\otimes m $ with $ (n,m)\in S^2\times S^2 $ and $ (n,m)=0 $, we define $ \pi_1(A)=n\otimes n $ and $ \pi_2(A)=m\otimes m $. I guess that if the homotopy class of $ \alpha $, denoted by $ [\alpha] $, is non-trivial, then there is one of $ [\pi_1(\alpha)] $ and $ [\pi_2(\alpha)] $ non-trivial. However I don not know how to prove this or give a conterexample. I have already know the covering space and fundamental group of $ N $ but I do not know how to go on. Can you give me some hints or references?

A further question is that if $ [\alpha] $ corresponds to the element of order $ 4 $ in the fundamental group, is such result true?

Comment: In my answer to your previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805824/how-to-determine-the-fundamental-group-of-n-otimes-n-m-otimes-mn-m-in-s2?rq=1), I showed that $\pi_1(N)\cong Q_8$. Consider the element of order $2$ in the fundamental group. Then group theory shows that its image is forced to be zero under both induced maps (The kernel of the induced maps are index 2 subgroups of $Q_8$). This gives a counterexample.

Comment: @Kevin. S Does it mean that if $ [\alpha] $ is a loop coresponding to the element of order $ 4 $, then either of $ [\pi_i(\alpha)] $ is non trivial?

Comment: That is what I'm not sure about, and it's not implied by my preceding comment. An observation is that we have $\pi_2=\pi_1\circ f$, where $f(n\otimes n-m\otimes m)=m\otimes m-n\otimes n$ (i.e., switching the role of $m,n$). If we can work out the induced map $f_\ast$ on the fundamental groups, then your further question will be answered. The only thing I can say about $f_\ast$ right now is that it's an isomorphism.

Comment: @LuisYankaAnnalisc: There are 6 elements of order 4 $\{\pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$.  There are 3 subgroups of order 4 $\langle i\rangle, \langle j\rangle, \langle k\rangle$.  Your maps $\pi_1, \pi_2$ each divides $Q_8$ by one of the subgroups of order 4.  So each $\pi_i$ leaves 4 elements of order 4 non-trivial.  Also, applying both $\pi_i$ leaves 2 elements of order 4 non-trivial.

Comment: @LuisYankaAnnalisc:  Correction, applying both $\pi_i$ leaves all 6 elements of order 4 non-trivial.  What I mean is for example if you reduce $Q_8\to Q_8/\langle i\rangle \times Q_8/\langle j\rangle$ then $\pm k$ remains non-trivial in both coordinates, but $\{\pm i, \pm j\}$ will also remain non-trivial each in one coordinate.  The kernel of the joint reduction is $\pm 1$.

Comment: @ChadK I want to ask why the kernels of $ \pi_1 $ and $ \pi_2 $ are different? If $ \operatorname{Ker}(\pi_1)=\operatorname{Ker}(\pi_2) $, your arguments may fails.

Comment: @LuisYankaAnnalisc:  They're different because $n\perp m$.  The only vector equivalent to $n$ is $-n$.  You can look at the triple $n, m, n\times m$ as corresponding to $i, j, k$ in $Q_8$.  The loop corresponding to $n$ is a rotation by $180^\circ$ around the axis $n$.  Doing this twice is a $360^\circ$ rotation in $SO(3)$ which corresponds to the element $-1$ in the fundamental group of $SO(3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

There's an action of $SO(3)$ on such pairs $(n, m)$ which for $O\in SO(3)$ sends the pair $(n, m)$ to $(On, Om)$.  The action is transitive.  You've correctly identified that the stabilizer of $(n, m)$ seen as a point on $N$ is a subgroup isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}\times\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$ with one generator sending $n$ to $-n$ and the other generator sending $m$ to $-m$.  The manifold $N$ is a quotient of $SO(3)$ by a $2\times 2$ discrete subgroup.  However, $SO(3)$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}P^3$ and is not simply connected.  It has fundamental group $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.

For a choice of $(n, m)$ let $k=n\times m$ (the cross product).  $k$ completes $(n, m)$ to a right-handed orthonormal basis.  Now let $R_\theta(k)$ be the rotation in $SO(3)$ around axis $k$ by angle $\theta$.  As you trace a loop in $SO(3)$ letting $\theta$ range over $2\pi$, in the manifold $N$, $(n, m)$ goes to $(-n,-m)$ at $\theta=\pi$ which is the same as $(n, m)$ in $N$, then after another turn of $\pi$ you get back to $(n, m)$.  At this point the images of the loop in $\Bbb{R}P^2$ in your maps $\pi_1, \pi_2$ is a trivial loop, because you've gone around twice.  In $SO(3)$ you've done one turn of $2\pi$, but that is not a trivial loop in $SO(3)$ because $SO(3)$ is not simply connected.  This loop is the generator of the fundamental group of $SO(3)$.

The correct thing is that $N$ is homemorphic to $SU(2)$ divided by the quaternion group $\{\pm 1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$.  $SU(2)$ is simply connected and is homeomorphic to $S^3$.  Then after dividing by the center of the quaternions which is $\{\pm 1\}$ you get $SO(3)$.  The quaternions divided by its center leaves you with a group which isomorphic to $2\times 2$, and then dividing by that you finally get $N$.

Comment: Is the reverse of this right ? That is, if one of $ [\pi_i(\alpha)] $, is non trivial, then $ [\alpha] $ is non-trivial.

Comment: I am not sure that I truly understand your answer. Here is my thought: if $ [\alpha] $ corresponds to the element with order $ 4 $ in the fundamental group, then either of $ [\pi_{i}(\alpha)] $ is non trivial. Is my thought true?

Comment: @LuisYankaAnnalisc:  1) The reverse is always right because a trivial element cannot map to a non-trivial element.  2) Your thought is true.  See my answer in a comment to the original post.